# Python-pptx font .name doesn't work. How to change all fonts?

Tags: python-pptx

I want to set all font to "Calibri", I use the following code to change font size,color sucessfully. **font.name** doesn't work however. I build a another ppt and try again, failed again.

And one more question, where can I get font name list?

"tmp.pptx" is just a common ppt file built through MS powerpoint. Any one can replicate this by open powerpoint. I put a rectangle in it and type some text, which was done in powerpoint. Now I want change the font type to 'Calibri' by using python-pptx pacakage rather than MS powerpoint. The problem is I can not change font type to what I set **font.name='Calibri"**.
After running the code, I open `tmp.pptx` through Powerpoint and found that the font remains `Times New Roman`, it didn't change to `Calibri`.

**In a word, How can I change all fonts from one type to another type such as Calibri\Arial whatever in the entire PPT. I mean every character in every slide change to the font I want.**

```
ppt=pptx.Presentation('tmp.pptx')
for slide in ppt.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            for para in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:

#If use "font=para.font",It can not identify font in autoshape. To change all fonts, a "for run in para.runs" should be used.

                for run in para.runs:
                    font=run.font
                    font.size=pptx.util.Pt(20)#succeeded
                    font.color.rgb=pptx.dml.color.RGBColor(140,0,0)#succeeded
                    font.name='Calibri'#failed
ppt.save('tmp.pptx')
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you mean "can't create a valid pptx?" or perhaps "Font name gets ignored / changed?" or something else?

Comment: Need a bit more information to help with the main question as what you posted 'should' work. What sort of shapes are these? Are you using a slide master?

Comment: I run the codes then I check what happened in tmp.pptx. color and size are changed successful. But font does not change to "Calibri" as what I set. My PPT is just a new built common one. To replicate this, build a new PPT and add any shape, text on it.

Comment: It seems just change the name of font. But didn't set it to "Calibri" really.

`font.name='Calibri'  

print(font.name)

out: Calibri`

However, when I open PPT file and check, the font didn't change to Calibri. It remains "Times New Roman".
So, "font.name=Calibri" didn't work, it didn't change the font type to Calibri.

Answer (score 2):

You can get font names like this

```
from pptx.text.fonts import FontFiles

fonts = FontFiles._installed_fonts()
font_names = [i[0] for i in fonts]
```

Comment: This fontfile seem not corresponds with the font in PPT. How can I find  it in fonts that PPT  provides  ?

Comment: Are you moving the .pptx to another machine - where the fonts might be different?

Comment: In powerpoint there is a font named "微软雅黑"(a Chinese font, which means microsoft yahei). But `pptx.text.fonts.FontFiles` doesn't include it. What't more ,  at the font path`C:\Windows\Fonts`, there is a "微软雅黑" font file.

Comment: I believe there are issues with non-western font names, as per - https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/768